# Нарисовать круг в Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pygame, рисование

Есть код, я пока смогу нарисовать только просто квадрат. 
Помогите нарисовать круг.

Данные, которые вводятся, это размер квадрата и насыщенность цвета.

**main.py**:

```
import pygame


RED = (70, 0, 0)
w, color = map(int, input().split())
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 700, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Прямоугольник")
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)

pygame.draw.rect(screen, (color, 0, 0), (100, 100, w, w))
pygame.display.flip()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass

pygame.quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pygame.draw.**circle**(surface, color, center, radius)

```
import pygame


RED = (70, 0, 0)
w, colorRect, colorCircle = map(int, input('\nВведите например 200 180 250: ').split())
pygame.init()
size = width, height = 700, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Прямоугольник")
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 50)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (colorRect, 0, 0), (100, 100, w, w))

pygame.draw.circle(screen, (colorCircle, 0, 0), (350, 350), w/2)            # +++

pygame.display.flip()

while pygame.event.wait().type != pygame.QUIT:
    pass
pygame.quit
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]